# why dns.gethotentry() method return addresslist as empty?

Tags: c#, dns

I use the following code to get the IP address:

```
var ip =  Dns.GetHostEntry(host);                     
var ipaddress = ip.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToString();
```

i can able to ping this hostname from command prompt.

but when i use `GethostEntry()`, it return the hostname correctly.

but the `AddressList` is empty.

And also it does not working, while i am giving local machine ipaddress.
why its happen?

Comment: What's the contents of your `host` variable? I just tested with `Dns.GetHostEntry("google.com")` and the result contains an `AddressList` with 16 entries.

Comment: Split your problem: is `ip.AddressList` empty of is the filter you use for FirstOrDefault that returns no addresses? Dump every element you find in `ip.AddressList`

Answer (score 1):

try using using this code:

```
PHostEntry host;
 string localIP = "";
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
  foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
{
 if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
 {
    localIP = ip.ToString();
   }
}
 return localIP;
```

Comment: although i have seen this solution in more questions, from some reason it works super on PC, but not on a mobile device. the device is connected correctly (in the same wifi network).
any ideas?