# Empty AddressList in GetHostEntry

Tags: c#, sockets

I am using following code to connect to remote host:

```
IPHostEntry hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry("172.29.65.33");
IPAddress address = hostname.AddressList[0]; // IndexOutOfRangeException
...
```

My question is why `AddressList` is empty? Host is there, no `SocketException` is thrown...

Some details: customer has upgraded Windows XP to 8.1 and then all troubles begun.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/156585/1997232) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31676533/1997232) topic, but unfortunately they are not useful to fix an issue, therefore asking it again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of resolving addresses via `Dns`

```
IPHostEntry hostname = Dns.GetHostEntry("172.29.65.33");
IPAddress address = hostname.AddressList[0];
...
IPEndPoint end = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
```

it can be simply parsed

```
IPEndPoint end = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("172.29.65.33"), port);
```

This will eliminate all problems (socket exception, empty address list, etc.) related to using `Dns`.